# GPU Acceleration and the Predict function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gpu

With the Mathematica Predict function, does it automatically use GPU acceleration? For example, with NetTrain, one has to specify TargetDevice->"GPU" to show they want to perform the calculation on the GPU, but this command is invalid for Predict. Does this mean it automatically uses GPU acceleration, or that it is simply not available with Predict?

Comment: GPU acceleration is not supported yet for Predict and Classify

Comment: @dan7geo Currently Predict and Classify DO support GPU via `TargetDevice -> "GPU"` - new recent feature.